# Custom HTTP headers with Commons HTTPClient?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

Is it possible to add your own headers using the Jakarta Commons HTTP Client? It seems like they only want you to override the default headers (eg: user agent): http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on the HttpGet and HttpPost classes. It's odd how they have it in 2 places, and with different functionality in each. So for example:

```
httpGet.setHeader(name, value);
```